# JCalendar click day to open a new JFrame

Tags: netbeans, jframe, jcalendar

I want to make JCalendar days clickable so that when clicked they open up a new JFrame with certain input fields that can be saved and edited. I am new to use of Netbeans and programming of this sort in general.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I figure it out. If anyone is interested then just set the property of JCalendar to JCalendarDateChanged and simply type in the line to open a new window.